# Rollup produces incorrect Dist structure when test are present

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, babeljs, rollupjs

I'm packaging a React module with rollup. Implemented with TypeScript. It contains Jest tests. Once I add a "test/mock/data.ts" to file, the output in "dist" changes its structure. A new "dist/src" folder appears. I need the build output to be the same as if the tests were not there at all. The library is open-source: https://github.com/kubevious/ui-properties

Directory Structure:

```
- src
  - index.ts
- test
  - mock
    - data.ts
- dist
  - index.js
  - index.d.ts // during the CI build this file is under src/
  - src // only if test/mock/data.ts file is there.
    - <other>
```

I have an ugly workaround. Would appreciate a proper solution. During the build:

```
$ mv .test test
$ npm run build
$ mv test .test
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "@kubevious/ui-properties",
  "version": "1.0.73",
  "description": "Kubevious UI Properties Components",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist",
  "files": [
    "dist/**/*",
    "public/**/*"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "test": "env TS_NODE_COMPILER_OPTIONS='{\"module\": \"commonjs\" }' jest",
    "test:watch": "jest --watch",
    "build": "rollup -c",
    "start": "rollup -c -w",
    "format": "prettier --write ./src/ ./test/",
    "format-check": "prettier --write ./src/ ./test/",
    "lint": "eslint",
    "storybook": "start-storybook -s ./public,./node_modules/@kubevious/entity-meta/public,./node_modules/@kubevious/ui-components/public -p 6006",
    "build-storybook": "build-storybook"
  },
  "author": "Ruben Hakopian <ruben.hakopian@gmail.com>",
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "@kubevious/entity-meta": "^1.0.69",
    "@kubevious/state-registry": "^1.0.13",
    "@kubevious/ui-alerts": "^1.0.49",
    "@kubevious/ui-components": "^1.0.242",
    "@kubevious/ui-framework": "^1.0.59",
    "@types/react-gauge-chart": "^0.3.1",
    "bootstrap": "^5.0.0-beta3",
    "chart.js": "^3.7.1",
    "chartjs-plugin-datalabels": "^2.0.0",
    "classnames": "2.3.1",
    "js-yaml": "^4.0.0",
    "react-chartjs-2": "^4.1.0",
    "react-gauge-chart": "^0.4.0",
    "the-lodash": "^2.0.9",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-actions": "6.5.7",
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "6.5.7",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "6.5.7",
    "@storybook/react": "6.5.7",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "12.1.5",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.24",
    "@types/js-yaml": "^4.0.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.6.0",
    "@types/react": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.27.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.27.1",
    "@babel/core": "7.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "8.2.5",
    "eslint": "8.17.0",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "^3.0.0",
    "jest": "26.6.3",
    "postcss": "8.4.14",
    "sass": "1.52.2",
    "prettier": "^2.1.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-babel": "5.3.1",
    "@rollup/plugin-commonjs": "22.0.0",
    "@rollup/plugin-json": "4.1.0",
    "rollup": "2.75.6",
    "rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external": "2.2.4",
    "rollup-plugin-postcss": "4.0.2",
    "rollup-plugin-typescript2": "0.32.1",
    "sass-loader": "13.0.0",
    "should": "13.2.3",
    "storybook-css-modules-preset": "1.1.1",
    "ts-jest": "26.5.6",
    "ts-node": "10.8.1",
    "tslib": "2.4.0",
    "typescript": "4.7.3",
    "rollup-plugin-sass": "1.2.12",
    "@storybook/preset-scss": "1.0.3",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.3",
    "@testing-library/dom": "8.13.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "13.5.0",
    "jest-environment-jsdom": "26.6.2",
    "css-loader": "6.7.1"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "the-lodash": "^2.0.9",
    "@kubevious/ui-framework": "^1.0.59",
    "@kubevious/ui-components": "^1.0.242",
    "@kubevious/ui-alerts": "^1.0.49",
    "@kubevious/entity-meta": "^1.0.69",
    "@kubevious/state-registry": "^1.0.13",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.3",
    "@types/react": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.3.3"
  }
}
```

**rollup.config.js**

```
import typescript from 'rollup-plugin-typescript2';
import { babel } from '@rollup/plugin-babel';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import peerDepsExternal from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import json from '@rollup/plugin-json';
import sass from 'rollup-plugin-sass';
import pkg from './package.json';

export default {
    input: 'src/index.ts',
    output: [
        {
            format: 'cjs',
            sourcemap: true,
            file: pkg.main,
            globals: { react: 'React' },
        },
    ],
    plugins: [
        typescript(),
        peerDepsExternal(),
        postcss({
            extract: false,
            modules: true,
            use: ['sass'],
        }),
        babel({ exclude: 'node_modules/**' }),
        commonjs({
            include: 'node_modules/**',
            namedExports: {
                'node_modules/react-is/index.js': ['isValidElementType'],
            },
        }),
        sass({ insert: true }),
        json(),
    ],
    external: ['react', 'react-dom'],
};
```

**tsconfig.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es6", "dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext","es2016", "es2017"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": false,
    "jsx": "react",
    "declaration": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "importHelpers": true,
  "include": ["./src"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "dist",
    "test",
    "**/*.stories.js",
    "**/*.stories.jsx",
    "**/*.stories.ts",
    "**/*.stories.tsx",
    "**/test",
    "**/test/**/*.test.js",
    "**/test/**/*.test.ts",
    "**/test/**/*.test.jsx",
    "**/test/**/*.test.tsx"
  ]
}
```

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but have you tried excluding the mock folder?  Edit: To clarify, I see you excluding the test folder, but I had an issue awhile back that forced me to exclude sub folders from my babel config.

Comment: @DocCaliban, I just tried excluding mock in tsconfig.json, but it still didn't help. If you have a couple of spare minutes, could you please give it a try on the repo? Thanks